# When is the assumption $\nabla \cdot D = 0$ justified for a waveguide?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, waveguide

Let's say we are looking at a waveguide with a perfect electric conductor as boundary (red), filled with air and another perfect conductor (red) inside. Say this waveguide is homogeneous in the longitudinal direction and infinitely long. We can look at the transverse plane of this waveguide:
[image]

If we look at the whole plane, one can say with confidence that $$\nabla \cdot D(x,y,z) =0  $$
But if we look at the static mode transverse electromagnetic wave (TEM) and take into account only a part of this plane, say only the green area, then the formula no longer holds.

[image]

So my question is: when calculating the electrical field of a waveguide using eigenvalue equations like $ \nabla \times \nabla \times E(x,y,z) = \omega^2 E(x,y,z) $, when can one assume that $ \nabla \cdot D(x,y,z) =0  $?

I am considering a 3D case, whereas the calculation of the eigenmodes can be limited to a 2D case. For this one often sets $\nabla \cdot D=0$. And this is why I need to know the answer to my question.

Comment: Are you taking the divergence in 3D or 2D? (in other words, are you considering a 3D vector $E(x,y,z)$ with 3 space variables or a 2D vector $E(x,y)$ with 2 space variables ?) I suggest you specify this in each equation in your question.

Comment: OK, so if you use the div curl = 0 identity in $ \nabla \times \nabla \times E(x,y,z) = \omega^2 E(x,y,z) $, don't you get $\nabla \cdot E=0$? (of course this is valid only in the free space, you can't include the conductor)

Comment: If I don't include the conductor, then the whole equation makes no sense. Without a conductor, the current wont flow. This must be included in the equation. And regarding the div curl - it's not that easy, since curl curl mus be calculated first. It results in a sum, which, when divergence is applied doesn't end up being $0$

Comment: You have div curl curl E = 0 on the left side, so you have div E = 0 on the right side. BTW, if you are TE, then $E_z = 0$, right? (assuming $z$ is the axis of the guide). Then the 2D divergence is zero as well (when there are no charges, in particular outside the conductor).

Comment: curl curl A = (div grad) A - grad (div A), according to vector identities. Applying div to it doesn't necessarily end up in $0$. But again, I can't only consider a free space and the trivial solution of the eigenvalue equation is not of interest to me.

Comment: The divergence of the curl of any vector field is always zero, see [Vector calculus identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Divergence_of_the_curl). Hence your divergence is zero, both in 2D (for TE modes) and 3D. Here you cannot ignore the central conductor. You need to set the same boundary condition as on the exterior conductor: the electric field tangent component must be zero. For numerical solving, you can use Nedelec's edge element H(curl).

Comment: I think we are writing about different things. In the eigenvalue equation from above div E must not be $0$. Simply take into account the third maxwells equation: $\nabla \cdot D = \rho $. And here I have 2 conductors, hence TEM-modes exist, hence surface charges exist, hence in a specific area $\nabla \cdot D \not= 0$.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong, the eigenvalue equation above implies that $\nabla \cdot E = 0$ *in the free space*. Proof: if $ \nabla \times (\nabla \times E) = \omega^2 E $, applying div to both sides yields $ \nabla \cdot \nabla \times (\nabla \times E) = \omega^2  \nabla \cdot E $. Using  $ \nabla \cdot \nabla \times A = 0$ for all field $A$ (with here $A=\nabla \times E$), we get $ 0 = \omega^2  \nabla \cdot E $, hence, if $\omega \neq 0$, we have $ 0 = \nabla \cdot E$, Q.E.D.

Comment: I agree, in free space it holds. But just try to some free charges (like in a cavity for example) and it wont hold. When it comes to the PEC (perfectly electric conductor) - sure, I agree that one needs a boundary condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51841/discussion-between-claude-chuber-and-kosha-misa).

Comment: Please, let us continue in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We suppose that the inside of the inner conductor is not empty. If you have $ \nabla \cdot E(x,y,z) = 0$ on a neighborhood $V$ of the inner conductor $C_{i}$ ($C_{i} \subset V$), you have no charges in $V$. In particular, you have no charges in the conductor itself, hence the electric field is zero inside the conductor.

We suppose that
$$\nabla \times \nabla \times E(x,y,z) = \omega^2 E(x,y,z).$$
It follows from the divergence free assumption and the vector calculus identity $\nabla \times \left( \nabla \times E \right) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot E) - \nabla^{2}E\ $ that
$$-\nabla^2 E(x,y,z) = \omega^2 E(x,y,z).$$
Hence the field $E$ is analytical in $V$ (property of the Laplace operator).

Being zero on an open subset of $V$ (the inside of the inner conductor) and analytical on $V$, the field $E$ is zero in the whole $V$.

In conclusion, the divergence free assumption *on a neighborhood of the inner conductor* implies that $E(x,y,z) = 0$ in the whole waveguide, including the inner perfect conductor. Which in turn implies that in the usual case where $E$ is not zero, the divergence free assumption *including the inner conductor* does not hold (that is, there *are* some charges moving around in the inner conductor).

Comment: If your conclusion is, that $E=0$, then how are the modes supposed to propagate?

Comment: @Kosha Misa : my conclusion (I will add it to the answer) is that your divergence free assumption does not hold. Note that this is not really surprising: you cannot expect the waveguide to transmit something without having charges moving around in the inner conductor (hence the non zero divergence there).